# what is dynamic credentials means?

Tags: database

i know what credentials is

```
A credential is an attestation of qualification, competence, or authority issued to an individual by a third party with a relevant or de facto authority or assumed competence to do so.

Examples of credentials include academic diplomas, academic degrees, certifications, security clearances, identification documents, badges, passwords, user names, keys, powers of attorney, and so on.
```

but what does dynamic credentials means????

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly given no context, but most likely it means things like "PIN tokens" or text message PIN systems, where you get a fresh PIN or other kind of token on request via a secure out-of-band channel (like your phone), which will then grant you access to a system.